# npm run build less error

Tags: webpack, less

I have an app to be deployed made by vue.. Whenever I run `npm run build` I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vux/src/styles/1px.less
Module build failed: Unknown word (23:5)

  21 | .vux-1px {
  22 |   &:before {
> 23 |     .setLine();
     |     ^
  24 |   }
  25 | }
  26 | 

 @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-3645c0bf!./~/vux-loader/src/style-loader.js!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:10-92
 @ ./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":1,"remove":true}!./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-3645c0bf!./~/vux-loader/src/style-loader.js!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vux/src/styles/weui/base/reset.less
Module build failed: Unknown word (24:5)

  22 | a {
  23 |     text-decoration: none;
> 24 |     .setTapColor();
     |     ^
  25 | }

 @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vux/src/styles/reset.less 3:10-84
 @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-3645c0bf!./~/vux-loader/src/style-loader.js!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":1,"remove":true}!./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-3645c0bf!./~/vux-loader/src/style-loader.js!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js

ERROR in ./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":1,"remove":true}!./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-3645c0bf!./~/vux-loader/src/style-loader.js!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: Error
    at /Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:141:35
    at /Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader.js:32:18)
    at /Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/css-loader/lib/processCss.js:222:4
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:58:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

ERROR in /Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":1,"remove":true}!/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js!/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/css-loader/index.js?sourceMap!/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter.js?id=data-v-3645c0bf!/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/vux-loader/src/style-loader.js!/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/ci/lion2/src/App.vue doesn't export content

  Build complete.

  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work.
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "lion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Snow <snow@unnotech.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.0",
    "vux": "^2.1.0-rc.48"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "eslint": "^3.14.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^2.0.7",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "opn": "^4.0.2",
    "ora": "^1.1.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-loader": "^10.3.0",
    "vue-moment": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-swipe": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.10",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.1.6",
    "vuex": "^2.1.2",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^4.1.2",
    "vux": "^2.1.0-rc.28",
    "vux-loader": "^1.0.35",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.16.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my 1px.less file

```
@import './weui/base/mixin/setOnepx.less';

.setLine(@c: #C7C7C7) {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid @c;
  color: @c;
  height: 200%;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.vux-1px, .vux-1px-t, .vux-1px-b, .vux-1px-tb, .vux-1px-l, .vux-1px-r {
  position: relative;
}

.vux-1px {
  &:before {
    .setLine();
  }
}

.vux-1px-t {
  &:before {
    .setTopLine();
  }
}

.vux-1px-b {
  &:after {
    .setBottomLine();
  }
}

.vux-1px-tb {
  &:before {
    .setTopLine();
  }
  &:after {
    .setBottomLine();
  }
}

.vux-1px-l {
  &:before {
    .setLeftLine();
  }
}

.vux-1px-r {
  &:after {
    .setRightLine();
  }
}
```

My webpack-config base (webpack.base.conf.js):

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

let webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    modules: [
      resolve('src'),
      resolve('node_modules')
    ],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'src': resolve('src'),
      'assets': resolve('src/assets'),
      'components': resolve('src/components')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: "pre",
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
         test: /\.less$/,
         use: [
               'style-loader',
               { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
               'less-loader'
               ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

const vuxLoader = require('vux-loader')
module.exports = vuxLoader.merge(webpackConfig, {
  options: {},
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'vux-ui'
    }
  ]
})
```

my webpack prod (webpack.prod.conf.js):

```
  var path = require('path')
  var utils = require('./utils')
  var webpack = require('webpack')
  var config = require('../config')
  var merge = require('webpack-merge')
  var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
  var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
  var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
  var env = config.build.env

  var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
    module: {
      rules: utils.styleLoaders({
        sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
        extract: true
      })
    },
    devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
    output: {
      path: config.build.assetsRoot,
      filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
      chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
    },
    plugins: [
      // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': env
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      }),
      // extract css into its own file
      new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
      }),
      // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
      // you can customize output by editing /index.html
      // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: config.build.index,
        template: 'index.html',
        inject: true,
        minify: {
          removeComments: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true
          // more options:
          // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
        },
        // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      }),
      // split vendor js into its own file
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: function (module, count) {
          // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
          return (
            module.resource &&
            /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
            module.resource.indexOf(
              path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
            ) === 0
          )
        }
      }),
      // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
      // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'manifest',
        chunks: ['vendor']
      })
    ]
  })

  if (config.build.productionGzip) {
    var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
      new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
        asset: '[path].gz[query]',
        algorithm: 'gzip',
        test: new RegExp(
          '\\.(' +
          config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
          ')$'
        ),
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
      })
    )
  }

  if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
    var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
  }

  module.exports = webpackConfig
```

utils.js

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

exports.assetsPath = function (_path) {
  var assetsSubDirectory = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? config.build.assetsSubDirectory
    : config.dev.assetsSubDirectory
  return path.posix.join(assetsSubDirectory, _path)
}

exports.cssLoaders = function (options) {
  options = options || {}
  // generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
  function generateLoaders (loaders) {
    var sourceLoader = loaders.map(function (loader) {
      var extraParamChar
      if (/\?/.test(loader)) {
        loader = loader.replace(/\?/, '-loader?')
        extraParamChar = '&'
      } else {
        loader = loader + '-loader'
        extraParamChar = '?'
      }
      return loader + (options.sourceMap ? extraParamChar + 'sourceMap' : '')
    }).join('!')

    // Extract CSS when that option is specified
    // (which is the case during production build)
    if (options.extract) {
      return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: sourceLoader,
        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
      })
    } else {
      return ['vue-style-loader', sourceLoader].join('!')
    }
  }

  // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/configurations/extract-css.html
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(['css']),
    postcss: generateLoaders(['css']),
    less: generateLoaders(['css', 'less']),
    sass: generateLoaders(['css', 'sass?indentedSyntax']),
    scss: generateLoaders(['css', 'sass']),
    stylus: generateLoaders(['css', 'stylus']),
    styl: generateLoaders(['css', 'stylus'])
  }
}

// Generate loaders for standalone style files (outside of .vue)
exports.styleLoaders = function (options) {
  var output = []
  var loaders = exports.cssLoaders(options)
  for (var extension in loaders) {
    var loader = loaders[extension]
    output.push({
      test: new RegExp('\\.' + extension + '$'),
      loader: loader
    })
  }
  return output
}
```

How can this problem be solved and what causes this error? I got stuck in this because I am almost zero knowledge on this type of front-end technology and was just asked to deploy

Comment: You didn't post your webpack config. But it looks like you're not applying the `less-loader` to the less files.

Comment: Please check the updates.. I added my webpack

Comment: I also added the less-loader and still error

Comment: It seems that you used `vue-cli` to generate those files and the LESS loader should be configured in `utils.styleLoaders`. Did you maybe change this line in [utils.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/build/utils.js#L51)?

Comment: I also included my utils.js for you to check..

Comment: That should be alright. The last thing I could imagine is that `vux-loader` at the end of your `webpack.base.conf.js` messes with that. But I have no clue what it does or how it does it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. If you have anything to suggest please feel free to comment